# Exact time when one makes an answer.

Tags: support, answers, timestamps

I have done an answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2020763/show-that-16-divides-n4-1-whenever-n-is-an-odd-number/2020771#2020771), but I wanted to see the exact hour I sent the answer, not *3 hours ago*. I know that I can do it in the comments, but how can I do that in answers?

Comment: meta.SE: [Should we see timestamp when an answer was appeared on?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236816)

Comment: Thanks. I though it was only for the comments.

Comment: Of course there are also other methods. Like getting the exact time from API or SEDE. But I do not know the details from the top of my head. If you are interested in other possibilities, you could try to search a bit on meta.SE. (Or simply wait a bit to see whether somebody will post a more detailed answer.)

Comment: Hold your mouse over the text that says "3 hours ago" (or whatever it is). The exact timestamp will appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comments, if you hover with the cursor over the text showing time (like "3 hours ago" or "yesterday"), a tooltip showing exact time will be shown. The same is true for many other timestamps in the Stack Exchange user interface. (And in general, tooltips are often used here as a way to provide some additional information. So hovering about something is worth trying if you are not sure what it means or what it is used for.)

I will also add screenshot taken from this meta.SE question: [Should we see timestamp when an answer was appeared on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236816/should-we-see-timestamp-when-an-answer-was-appeared-on)

> [image]